# Automate website validation testing using powershell script?

Tags: python, powershell, scripting, automation, automated-tests

I have a website in which their are couple of forms which needs to be filled one by one to reach the final answer which is a token no. uniquely generated for each user.

Manually testing it on regular bases takes following steps:

1) open www.xyz.com

2) fill in first form details i.e. Name, age, Sex click next

3) fill in second form details i.e. Address, zip, employment type click next

4) fill in third form details .... so on till form 5 and then click finish.

5) after clicking finish I am redirected to final page with a Token no.

Question: How to automate this test using PowerShell script or any other scripting language, So that when I run the script and it completes all the step one by one and Give me the token no. as output if Test passes successfully ?

Comment: python in combination with selenium will help you a great deal

Answer (score 1):

To give you a set off, you load your document in Chrome or Explorer with the developers tools activated (Press F12) and inspect the objects you want to find. You will be able to see the DOM of the document loaded for the website.

Here is a sample login:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true
$username="username@domain.com"
$password="password"
$ie.Navigate("https://www.yourwebsite.com")
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true)
{
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
}
$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('Email_ID').value="$username"
$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('Password').value="$password"
$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('Login_ID')
$Link.click() #or $Link.submit()
$ie.Quit()
```

Once you are logged in, you can start picking the objects and proceed in the same way.

Note: Pick the proper ObjectIds and put it in the getElementByID accordingly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In your while statement, you can just enter `While ($ie.Busy) { }` instead of your current statement.  I'd suggest a kill-process check `Do { logic } While ($ie.Busy)` just in case IE hangs so your PS session doesn't also hang with an infinite loop.